# Django only one user/one date in same model

Tags: django, model, unique

I have a table that several users will add dates to.
Each user can add a date. But you can only add that date once.
How can I prevent a user from adding the same date more than once?
Thanks in advance!

models.py

```
class MarcacaoRefeicoes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-data']
        verbose_name = 'Marcação de Refeição'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Marcação de Refeições'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='marcacao_refeicoes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='Data')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.data)
```

views.py

```
def marcacao_refeicoes_adicionar(request, pk=None):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
    form = MarcacaoRefeicoesForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, initial={'user': pk})
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Marcação adicionada com sucesso!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("marcacao_refeicoes", kwargs={'pk': pk}))
    context = {
        "user": user,
        "form": form,
    }

    return render(request,
                  'gestao/area_individual/marcacao_refeicoes/adicionar.html', context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) - it will forbid to have same combination of user and date.

```
class MarcacaoRefeicoes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'data']
        ordering = ['-data']
        verbose_name = 'Marcação de Refeição'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Marcação de Refeições'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='marcacao_refeicoes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='Data')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.data)
```

If you are on django 2.2, you should use [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) instead, since `unique_together` might get deprecated later on.

```
class MarcacaoRefeicoes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'data'], name='unique_item')
        ]
        ordering = ['-data']
        verbose_name = 'Marcação de Refeição'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Marcação de Refeições'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='marcacao_refeicoes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='Data')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.data)
```

Comment: That's not how you define constraints. They need to be defined in the `constraints` attribute inside Meta; `constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'data'], name='unique_item')]`